# Query optimization- How to achieve that in this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

How can I optimize this query ? I have created indexes,partitions,increased worker memory but the execution time is still 35s. How can I minimize it to 10-15 seconds?
Update :

1. Removed conversion of every time stamp from utc to local time i.e. time_stamp AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AT TIME ZONE which improved the performance by approximately 5 seconds. Current execution time : 36.5 seconds.

```
explain analyse select
DATE_TRUNC('day', time_stamp) as "time_stamp",
COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS alarm_count,
COUNT(DISTINCT patient_id) AS patient_count
FROM
alarm_management.alarm
WHERE
tenant_name = 'abc'
and
unit = ANY('{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k}'::text[])
AND
time_stamp BETWEEN '2021-09-15 02:25:00' AND '2021-12-14 04:36:45'
AND
severity_label = ANY('{a,b,c,d}'::text[])

AND derived_label IS NOT NULL
GROUP by 1
```

Explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) output-

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=3064683.77..3215681.44 rows=308821 width=24) (actual time=24242.730..35145.380 rows=91 loops=1)
  Group Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, alarm_hospitalc_burn_2021_9.time_stamp))
  ->  Sort  (cost=3064683.77..3101468.12 rows=14713740 width=40) (actual time=24167.513..25036.293 rows=16369464 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, alarm_hospitalc_burn_2021_9.time_stamp))
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1672081kB
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1312964.42 rows=14713740 width=40) (actual time=0.308..20958.290 rows=16369464 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on alarm_hospitalc_burn_2021_9  (cost=0.00..7175.10 rows=69691 width=40) (actual time=0.307..127.521 rows=94286 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((derived_label IS NOT NULL) AND (time_stamp >= '2021-09-15 02:25:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (time_stamp <= '2021-12-14 04:36:45'::timestamp without time zone) AND (tenant_name = 'HospitalC'::text) AND (severity_label = ANY ('{"Short Yellow",Cyan,Red,Yellow}'::text[])) AND (unit = ANY ('{Burn,Delivery,EDI,EDT,EDW,ICU1,ICU2,ICU3P,ICU4P,PP,Tele}'::text[])))
```

Comment: How much data are you dealing with? Also, why are you using a function there? Why not just a `CASE` in the `SELECT`?

Comment: I am dealing with around 10GB size of data. This function is used in many queries which is why I am not using case in select.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions And start with EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this query

Comment: `AT TIME ZONE 'utc'` or `AT TIME ZONE time_zone`? I suppose the former for why would you store the timestamp in one timezone and store another timezone in the same row. Then, depending on selectivity, the ideal index would be `create index idx1 on person ( (time_stamp at time zone 'utc'), name );` or `create index idx2 on person ( name, (time_stamp at time zone 'utc') );` Which index have you tried?

Comment: Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 545640kB
Your work_mem is too small. Try using 1GB or so. SET work_mem TO '1GB';  and then run EXPLAIN again.

Comment: Weird function. hour -> hour, second ->day, month -> day, century -> day, typo -> day. Doesn't really enhance readability in my opinion.

Comment: With Frank's suggestion to change the function, you can make the group expression third column in the functional index.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have increased the worker memory to 2GB and now its Quick Sort not external merge disk.

Comment: Where is the *rest* of the plan?

Comment: The function is probably the least of your worries. The non-sargable query predicates look much more troubling. Provide proper information as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) and you'll get better answers.

Comment: Why do you have so many different table partitions? And I would have expected some form of parallelism in the query plan, but I don't see it. Check the PostgreSQL version you're using and the documentation in how to activate/use it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-query.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens These table partition is a requirement. My postgreSQL version is 12.7. How can I achieve parallelism in the query plan ? max_worker_processes and max_parallel_workers are set to 8 and I can't change it because it needs a server restart. max_parallel_workers_per_gather is 2 and reducing that is not making much difference in the query plan.

Comment: From the manual: "Parallel aggregation is not supported if any aggregate function call contains DISTINCT or ORDER BY ". That explains why there's no parallel plan. Over 40 partitions also doesn't help, it doesn't make a lot of sense from a technological stand point. A requirement should support a functional request and that's not clear to me. But I don't have the whole picture either. Maybe processing half a million records per second is the max your system can do with these requirements. Maybe you need a work around like a materialised view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can be written in SQL, that might be slightly faster:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.get_time_group ( _date_type TEXT ) 
RETURNS TEXT 
LANGUAGE sql -- SQL is good enough
IMMUTABLE -- better for performance, next call is faster because of caching
AS 
$$
    SELECT CASE $1 
            WHEN 'hour' THEN 'hour' 
            ELSE 'day' 
        END;
$$;
```

But the most important thing is the query plan.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. And `IMMUTABLE` even makes the function valid for the use in a functional index.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: The function body can now be inlined in the query, as if the function isn't there at all. More about this in the wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions

Comment: Thanks Thorsten and Frank. But I think even if I remove the function and for now just hardcode the text to 'date' in the query i.e. DATE_TRUNC('day',xx,xx) The query is still taking 40+ seconds to execute. Is there any alternate solution ?

Comment: @Anonymous_student: Where is your (complete!) query plan? And the DDL for this table. We have no idea what is going on, you have to show us. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have updated the query and execution plan.